# What data type should be used to reference serialized objects by ID?

Tags: java, xml, spring, serialization

I have a bunch of classes that will be instantiated and passed between my JS front-end and Spring MVC.

I'm using [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to serialize my object as XML for persistent storage and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to pass it to my UI as JSON. Consequently I need to have an ID attribute that is used to reference an object, and this needs to be consistent in both the JSON, POJO and XML.

This means I need an ID attribute in my Java class. What type should I declare it as? I've seen `int` being used in the [Simple library tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) and I've also seen `UUID` being used [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56).

The [Simple library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#cycles) creates `id` and `ref` attributes (or any other that you provide) to maintain references:

```
<parent name="john" id="1">
   <children>
      <child id="2" name="tom">
         <parent ref="1"/>
      </child>
   </children>
</parent>
```

The accompanying Java to read it back in:

```
Strategy strategy = new CycleStrategy("id", "ref");
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
File source = new File("example.xml");
Parent parent = serializer.read(Parent.class, source);
```

The `id` isn't in the original Java object however, so it won't be passed with the JSON to the UI. Should I define a `private UUID uid;` and pass that, while also letting Simple generate the auxiliary `id` and `ref` attributes it uses, or is there a way to use a single Java attribue to do both?

EDIT: Hibernate has an `@Id` annotation, but I can't find something similar for Simple. Will this do?

```
@Attribute
private int id;
```

The problem is that I'll need to instantiate and pass it as JSON, but it needs to be unique as well (meaning it'd be easier to use UID). Also, will Simple use this `id` for its `ref`?

EDIT 2:

Using `id` as an attribute and then using the CycleStrategy causes it to use the value you define from the class and not the internal ones it uses in the XML which the `ref` point to... I'm using two attributes for now - a `uuid` I generate together with the `id` Simple uses internally.